# How to create a ListView in Nativescript-vue with a staggered or grid layout?

Tags: listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to create a ListView in Nativescript-Vue with a staggered or grid layout, but I cannot find any information in the docs on how this is done.

In Nativescript UI, this is done as follows:

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ items }}"> 
    <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
        <lv:ListViewGridLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" />
    </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        ...
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

In Nativescript-Vue, I currently have this:

```
<ListView for="item in items">
    <v-template>
        ...
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```

But how do I add the grid layout style?

Comment: RadListView (`nativescript-ui-listview`) and ListView (`tns-core-modules/ui-listview`) are different controls and at this very moment the RadListView is not supported in nativescript-vue. The ListView does not support staggered layout (only the RadListView)

Comment: Allright, but I was able to import the `<RadCalendar>` element into nativescript-vue by using this line: `Vue.registerElement('RadCalendar', () => require('nativescript-ui-calendar').RadCalendar);`

Would it be possible to implement the RadListView with a staggered layout that way?

Comment: The `nativescript-ui-calendar` has a Vue version but the RadListView implementation for Vue is still in process. There are some conceptual issues that the team need to solve (the difference in templating in Vue) and only after taht the version for Vue will be published - track it here https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction

Comment: @NickIliev Thanks. Will keep checking the progress on this issue.

Comment: @Hans I don't really understand your question what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to have a gridlayout that will be filled with data from your array? Or do you want to have a List that has a template with a grid inside?